# Optimize memory usage for electron app when using canvas context

Tags: javascript, canvas, electron

I am working to port a WPF application to more platforms and at this moment, Electron app is the most well-known and easily to work with compared to others. And I definitely aware of the memory hog of Electron app since it includes the entire Chrome engine. Not so fond of it, but right now, it is the best choice in term of time and maintainability.

Basically, the app that is currently being worked on is just a screenshot capture of the desktop or an application window and send it over the network. So far, I was able to replicate the same similar functionality in the Electron app compared to the WPF version. However, when monitor the performance, the Electron app is using too much memory footprint. The main renderer process take as much as 200MB ram and maybe more compared to the WPF version, which at most up to 100MB. That does not include the other 2 processes (main and the GPU process), which in total could more than 400MB-500MB per session. Initially at startup, it is at least at the level of the peak WPF version, which I can tolerate it. However, as the program does the logic, it continues to consume lot of memory. So far, I was able to cut down some of that if not using other javascript libraries, just only the native libs.

Below is the code that does the logic:

```
function capture(vWidth, vHeight) {
    var timeInterval;
    var canvas = document.getElementById('videoCanvas');
    var video = document.getElementById("videoFrame");
    canvas.height = vHeight;
    canvas.width = vWidth;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    timeInterval = setInterval(() => {
        if(stream) {                    
                let frame = captureFrame(ctx, video);
                sendingChunk(frame);
                frame = null;
        } else {
            clearInterval(timeInterval);
        }
    }, 900);
}

function captureFrame(ctx, videoFrame) {
  ctx.drawImage(videoFrame, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  return ctx.canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.8);
}
```

I believe that is just a most standard way to capture the frame of the video feed from the getUserMedia that Chrome uses to stream out the current desktop or an application window. In the code, I notice that `captureFrame()` function is probably the main culprit as it has to deal with canvas drawing the video frame. Also, `setInterval()` could contribute more to that as well.

So anyone has any idea to optimize this? Are there other ways to achieve the same functionality but with better performance?

Comment: What is `sendingChunks`? Do you really need to send DATAURIs? Can't you directly send the MediaStream feeding tour video over WebRTC? This way you wouldn't need canvas at all.

Comment: That would be really be great, but at the moment, the server is not handling any WebRTC stuff. It is planned for the next revision though as WebRTC reaches mature status. For now, `sendingChunks` is basically what is described, as it sends Base64 format to the server through chunking as needed.